# Issue with for loop, it reads both if and else if statement

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have an issue with  my for loop. It goes through two arrays and compares the account number and PIN.  An `if` statement checks if the combination of account number and PIN are correct. Since I changed this part `(user_Account != accounts[i] || user_Pin != pins[i])` from the original `(user_Account == accounts[i] && user_Pin != pins[i])`, this happens. Before that it worked perfectly, but I was afraid that if someone types wrong account, then the program might crash so I made that change. Here is part of the code, I can post more if needed. Please have one thing in mind I am in beginning class, so no advanced changes or recommendations, I need something on my current level. I appreciate any help.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    if(user_Account == accounts[i] && user_Pin == pins[i])
    {
        cout << "You entered correct combination of account and pin number." << endl;
    }
    else if(user_Account != accounts[i] || user_Pin != pins[i])
    {
        cout << "You entered wrong account and/or wrong pin number. Please start over." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is `if (x) else if (!x)`, just drop the second if. You will save yourself headaches trying to fix logic reversal as well as being completely unnecessary.

Comment: Just as a quick thing PIN stands for  Personal Identification Number, so PIN number would be  Personal Identification Number Number... :)

Answer (score 0):

When you converted from

```
(user_Account == accounts[i] && user_Pin != pins[i])
```

to

```
(user_Account != accounts[i] || user_Pin != pins[i])
```

you should have converted to:

```
(user_Account != accounts[i] || user_Pin == pins[i])
```

You are actually applying something called [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), and it's worth reading up on them for the history at least :).

Regarding if you should have separate if-else clauses for account fail compared to PIN fail - that's kind of a design decision. If someone was trying to break into your 'bank' and was guessing both the PIN and the account number from, say, looking over someone's shoulder, then seperate error messages would help him/her find the correct combination more quickly. On the other hand, if (more likely) a customer has just make a typing error, it's nice to have a message telling them. It's pretty much up to you.

Comment: but then what if someone types wrong pin? or do you think I should have 3 if statements?

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two cases:

1. Both account id and password match

   or
2. At least one doesn't match

I would just save yourself the headache of a second condition and let the check be this:

```
if (user_Account == accounts[i] && user_Pin == pins[i])
    // accounts match message
else
    // accounts don't match message
```

Also, a pointer on your for loop: you might want to make sure the for loop doesn't keep going when one of the arrays runs out, so your **for loop** signature could be this:

```
for (int i = 0; (i < accounts::size) && (i < pins::size); i++)
```

Comment: for this I need a class, right "for (int i = 0; (i < accounts::size) && (i < pins::size); i++)" and we are not there  yet  in the book. So I can't use it.     and this runs through both statements 
 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
 {
        if (user_Account == accounts[i] && user_Pin == pins[i])
  {
   cout << "You entered correct combination of account and pin number." << endl;
  }

  else
        {
            cout << "accounts don't match" << endl;
   return 0;
        }
 }

Comment: so I did this 
 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
 {
        if (user_Account == accounts[i] && user_Pin == pins[i])
  {
   cout << "You entered correct combination of account and pin number." <<endl; goto start;    /*and start  is below just in front of menu options, so if it is correct it skips the second else statement  */                                     
  }

  else
        {
            cout << "accounts don't match" << endl;
   return 0;
        }
 }

Comment: If you're using an array, you're already using a class. Your array **accounts** is an object of the class **array** http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/